# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" while using OneHotEncoder for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm using LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder to handle 'categorical data' in my dataset. In my data set there is a column which can have two values either 'Petrol' or 'Diesel' and I want to encode that column. I'm running this piece of code and its giving an error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('ToyotaCorolla.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:10].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values

labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Column[3] is the one which will have categorical value. But it is showing up an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Diesel'".
I dont know where I'm going wrong. please help. Thanks!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `spyder` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `scikit-learn`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`categorical_features` is deprecated, instead directly transform your categorical feature

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
feature = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 3].reshape(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

this error comes when your x is having a column with categories in string format
 when I had had this error
I used label encoder to  all the categorical columns in X  as you did to column 3
and then apply one hot encoder to column 3

"so what you have to do is LabelEncode all the categorical columns in X and then apply one hot encoder to your desired column"